# First vs at first

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, grammaticality

I usually ask people this **first**, but I haven't done so with you. What's your favorite music?

I usually ask people this **at first**, but I haven't done so with you.
What's your favorite music?

Are both examples grammatically correct? What's the difference in their meaning? Are **first** and **at first** interchangeable here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First* implies that it is literally the first question that you ask them. *At first* could mean that you ask it quite early in the conversation, or soon after having met them.